# Given a dictionary and a sequence return its total in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
dependent = ["R", "S"]

L = {"R": [0.8, 0.2], "S": [0.5, 0.5], "K": [0.1, 0.1]}

sequence = [[0,0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1,1]]
```

I wish to generalize a certain approach without imports.

Given these three list and dictionaries output the sequence. so for R and S the first element implies R = 0, S = 0. What I want is:

0.8 x 0.5 + 0.8 x 0.5 + 0.2 x 0.5 + 0.2 x 0.5

basically

(R = 0 x S = 0) + (R = 0 x S = 1) + (R = 1 x S = 0) + (R = 1 x S = 1) as given by the sequence list.

I know I iterate from the sequence but after that I'm not sure how to use dependent and L concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to leave so I can't finish this, but this is where I'm at. Maybe it will help set you on a path to solve it!

```
dependent = ["R", "S"]

L = {"R": [0.8, 0.2], "S": [0.5, 0.5], "K": [0.1, 0.1]}

sequence = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
my_list = []
for item in sequence:
    item_total = 1
    for index in range(len(item) - 1):
        print(L[dependent[index]][item[index]])
        item_total = item_total * L[dependent[index]][item[index]]
        # print(item_total)
    my_list.append(item_total)

print(my_list)
total = sum(my_list)
print(total)
```

Right now I'm getting

```
0.8
0.8
0.2
0.2
[0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2]
2.0
```

Which is obviously not correct, but close. There's just an indexing error somewhere D:

Comment: If dep were ["R", "S", "K"] and sequence = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]] this wouldn't work.

Comment: @bonsaget and in this case you want R X S X K? it's all just multiplied together?

Comment: basically I think? With respect to the sequence. Dep could be ["A", "B", "C", D"] and its value would be in L. To generalize this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

Given that you don't want to use imports, I think the best approach is to define
a function such as:

```
def cartesian(items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [
            [x] + c 
            for x in items[0] 
            for c in cartesian(items[1:])
        ]
```

to get the cartesian product of given iterables.

We want to apply this function just to your dependent items, so first:

```
dep_items = [v for k, v in L.items() if k in dependent]
```

and then calculate the product:

```
>>> sum([eval("*".join(map(str, c))) for c in cartesian(dep_items)])
1.0
```

**Update**

After reading one of your comments and I believe I misunderstood the role of `sequence` in your question, i.e. `sequence` is always available and not made of all combinations, so you don't need the `cartesian` function. 
In that case, I believe `sequence` and `dependent` should keep the same order, so first:

```
items = [L[k] for k in dependent]
```

then I get combinations according to `sequence`:

```
combos = [[items[i][ind] for i, ind in enumerate(s)] for s in sequence]
```

and finally calculate the sum of the products.

I'll show an example with a particular `dependent` and `sequence` you requested in a comment:

```
>>> dependent = ["R", "S", "K"]
>>> sequence = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]] 
>>> items = [L[k] for k in dependent]
>>> combos = [[items[i][ind] for i, ind in enumerate(s)] for s in sequence]
>>> sum([eval("*".join(map(str, c))) for c in combos])
0.09000000000000002
```